# Switching values

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am struggling with a generic regex to switch values around.
I want a quick way to rearrange

```
{"AAA","AA1"},
```

into

```
{"AA1","AAA"},
```

ideally using notepad++

Cheers.

Comment: would 'replace' not be suitable?

Comment: I have thousands of different values, I'm trying to use replace by regex but struggling with a generic regex.

Comment: How "generic" should it be? Do you want to replace each `A` with `1` and vice versa, or only for `AA1` and `AAA`, or only if the two are right next to each other? Should it swap any two elements within `{...,...}`?

Comment: I think the question and example explains itself enough. It does not mention swapping A with 1, if you have down voted because you find regex easy or have loads of experience with regex's then good for you... but I don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Replace with Ctrl+H & tick the *Regular Expression* box

Find: `\{(.*),(.*)\}`

Replace With: `{\2,\1}`

(Assumes no `}` in the quoted values)

Comment: Beware of unwanted changes inside `{"AAA","AA1","AA2"},` with this regex.

Answer (score 1):

in notepad++ :

find :

```
\{\s*\"(.*?)\"s*\,\s*\"(.*?)\"\s*}
```

replace by :

```
{"\2","\1"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this one](https://regex101.com/r/gL4wY8/2):

```
Search: (\{\s*")([^"}]*)(",\s*")([^"}]*)("\})
Replace: \1\4\3\2\5
```

Answer (score 0):

Pattern: `\{("[^"]*")\s*,\s*("[^"]*")\}`
Replacement: `{$2,$1}`

Explanation:

- group the `"..."` parts
- use the inverse character class `[^"]*` to match everything until the first `"`
- reverse their orders with the backreferences: `{$2,$1}`